# laravel - access variable outside loop

Tags: laravel

my code:

```
$atts->each(function($row){
  if($row->key == 30){
    $flag = $row->value;
    echo $flag;
  }
});
```

The value of $flag will be printed to the site. However, when I try to use the variable $flag outside the loop the variable is unknown.

Can someone tell me what I am missing or what has to be done to have access to that variable?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,

Andreas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to define that variable in the current scope and import that variable into your callback's scope with `use`.

```
$flag = null;
//Access flag by reference
$atts->each(function($row) use (&$flag) {
   ...
});
```

Since we're using Laravel Collections, I suggest you not use each() for this.

```
if ($row = $atts->where('key', 30)->first()) {
   $flag = $row->value;
}
```

This assumes there is only one row with a key of 30 though.